# ASP.NET Core 2 - Do not compile resx files

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, resx

With previous MVC/ASP.NET when deployed code the resx files were deployed non-compiled and was able to modify the key,values and changes were reflected. With ASP.NET Core 2+ I noticed resx get compiled into dll.

I edited .csproj with

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Resources\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After editing the .csproj and redeploy, the Resource folder and resx files are there, but when I edit on the server in notepad the edits are not reflecting. Seems like it is still required to be compiled.

Any way to set so that the resx files can be updated without compiling? or is there a different approach in asp.net core 2?

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer select the item you want published.

Look in the Properties section at the bottom of Solution Explorer

- Change the Build Action to Content
- Change the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always

[image: resx properties]

You can also check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: After I made the two changes mentioned above, get exception reading the key from resource file inside layout.cshtml file
MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "ProjectA.Resources.layoutskin.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "ProjectA" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
Inside layout.cshml: include: `@using ProjectA.Resources` and call: `@layoutskin.WelcomeText`. It worked before making the two changes. any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I create a new class library project for resources only then I add it as a reference to the main project.

This way I can edit, compile and upload the resources library project without the need to build and upload the whole project.

Btw, resource .resx file type is not listed in class library projects new file dialog, but you can create a text file and change its extension manually to .resx an it will work fine.

Comment: Sorry didnt have a chance to reply earlier. I moved the resx files to a library project. Had ASP.NET Core2 referenced the library dll and it works. But back to the issue, when updating the resx files outside of visual studio and saving and when running  the code (that references the resx library) the new changes do not show. Only when I rebuild it shows. any chance you can look at code? somehow show you the sample code/structure i created. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It maybe useful for someone: using .po files instead of .resx files by installing orchard.core package

[Configure portable object localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0)